# How to change price (Custom Price) of Bundle Child products during add to cart using observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, addtocart, bundled-product

I am trying to change the price of Bundle products during add to cart using observer in Magento 1.9

Till now I am using below code in observer but it changes the price of parent product not the child products.

```
<?php class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer { 

public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {

    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($item->getProductId());

         $bundleType = $product->getTypeId();

         if ($bundleType == 'bundle') {

         $collection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

         foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $_item) {
$custom_price = 20;
$productPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getFinalPrice();

  $finalPrice = (int)$custom_price + (int)$productPrice;

    if($finalPrice > 0){
        $_item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

         } 

         }    

}
}
```

Please help me How can I change the price of child products.

Thanks

Comment: which event are you observing there? and why are you adding the custom price to ALL items in the cart?

Comment: I am observing sales_quote_add_item event. I need to change custom price of each item as per client requirement. Do you have any other solution?